# Computer cannot start after fresh reinstall windows

Tags: windows

I don't understand that StackExchange, where I can post question about computers, so I think, this will be good.

Friend of mine wanted to reinstall windows and clear everything. He had windows XP. He don't know a lot of computers, so I decided, I will do that. I took his HDD to home and connected to my computer. Installation of windows XP started and everything worked well.

But when I bring HDD back to his computer and connected it, all I get after start computer is that (picture bellow). It is something like cursor, flashing on screen and never end. Does someone know, what could went wrong, when that worked well in my PC and its same windows, which he had before? (Sorry for bad english)

[image]

Comment: You and your friend have the same computer model?

Comment: This question is off-topic. You should post that question in the Super User community forum.

Comment: No. I have Gigabyte motherboard and he (I think) has intel motherboard. But, he had XP before, same what is there now.

Comment: Windows is configured based on the hardware underneath. Installing windows in one system and then placing that hard drive in another usually does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Because first time he wanted Windows 7, but his DVD-RAM din't want to boot Win7 disk so we decided I take HDD. You should post it as answer, so this question should be closed.

Comment: I just provided an answer in the comments to help you. This question will be perhaps removed as it is off-topic for the stack overflow. You should post question about general hardware and software issues of computers in the Super User forum in Stack Exchange. Anyways I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it in future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows is configured based on the hardware underneath. Installing windows in one system and then placing the HDD in another usually does not work. Use a Bootable USB to install Windows in the system as the DVD Drive isn't functional.